# Nested dictionary to list of strings - typeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a nested dictionary which I want to convert to a list of strings.
e.g.
I have this input:

```
var group = {
    '5': {
        '1': {
            '1': [1,2,3],
            '2': [1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1': [2,4],
            '2': [1]
        }
    },
    '1': {
        '1':{
            '1':[1,2,5],
            '2':[1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1':[2,3]
        }
    }
};
```

I want this output:

```
a = ["5.1.1.1","5.1.1.2","5.1.1.3"..... "1.2.1.3"]
```

I started with this recursive function:

```
function printValues(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key)
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            printValues(obj[key]);   
        } else {
            console.log(obj[key]);    
        }
    }
}
```

But t doesn't work yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and get the most nested items first and build the wanted strings.

> How does it work?
>
> It takes from an object all entries (key/value pairs) and pushes a spreaded array to the result set.
>
> The array for spreading is either
>
> - an array of values or
> - an array from calling the function again with the object `v` as parameter
>
> Both arrays are mapped by taking the key `k` from the object and an item from the array for getting the wanted style `n.m`.
>
> For example take a sub `{ 1: [2, 4], 2: [1] }` object and get an array of key/values.
>
> ```
> [
>     [1, [2, 4]],
>     [2, [1]]
> ]
> ```
>
> This is the result of the first iteration of `reduce`. The order is the logical run from the inside:
>
> 1. yes, it's an array,
> 2. take `v` with `[2, 4]`,
> 3. map this value together with `k` `1`,
> 4. get array of `['1.2', '1.4']`,
> 5. spread this array and
> 6. push each element as parameter.
>
> Then take the second loop and get `['1.2', '1.4', '2.1']`.
>   This result is taken as value from `getPathes` and mapped with the actual key in front of each string.
>
> The result is a build by a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for getting the most inner array and put the key in front of each item.

```js
function getPathes(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        r.push(...(Array.isArray(v) ? v : getPathes(v)).map(l => `${k}.${l}`));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var group = { 5: { 1: { 1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1] }, 2: { 1: [2, 4], 2: [1] } }, 1: { 1: { 1: [1, 2, 5], 2: [1] }, 2: { 1: [2, 3] } } },
    result = getPathes(group);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you its work. but can you please explain how the function works? it's hard to understand...

Comment: @YossiMenasherov, please see edit. and ask if something is unclear.

Comment: now i wish to create a function that get paths (like 5.1.1.1 and etc..) and return a nested dictionary. may you help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries` with this recursive function:

```js
var group = {
    '5': {
        '1': {
            '1': [1,2,3],
            '2': [1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1': [2,4],
            '2': [1]
        }
    },
    '1': {
        '1':{
            '1':[1,2,5],
            '2':[1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1':[2,3]
        }
    }
};

let r = []
const getPaths = (p, v) => {
  if (Array.isArray(v)) {
    v.forEach(e => r.push([...p, e].join('.')))
  } else {
    Object.entries(v).forEach(([k, v]) => getPaths([...p, k], v))
  }
}

getPaths([], group)
console.log(r)
```

Comment: now i wish to create a function that get paths (like 5.1.1.1 and etc..) and return a nested dictionary. 
may you help me with that? 
Thanks!

Comment: @YossiMenasherov I'm not sure what you mean. Create a question, then link me to it :)