# Javascript - nested dictionary from array of strings separated with dots

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to **translate** an array **to** nested dictionary.

In case i have a string array. each string combined from numbers that seprated by dots,
and each number means a key in the translated dictionary. (except the last number)

e.g.

i have this array:
`array = ["5.1.1.1","5.1.1.2","5.1.1.3",..."5.2.1.2","5.2.1.4"..."1.1.1.1"..."1.2.1.3"]`

and i need output to be this:

```
var output = {
    '5': {
        '1': {
            '1': [1,2,3],
            '2': [1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1': [2,4],
            '2': [1]
        }
    },
    '1': {
        '1':{
            '1':[1,2,5],
            '2':[1]
        },
        '2':{
            '1':[2,3]
        }
    }
};
```

i have an opposite function, which get a nested dictionary and her output is an array.

link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191937/7593555

Thanks for helping :).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you starting off with the assumption that every string will have exactly 4 elements every time? We don't have to worry about '5.1.2' or '5.1.1.1.2' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function, using the output from your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191831/nested-dictionary-to-list-of-strings-typescript/59192010?noredirect=1#comment104948410_59192010):

```js
const arr = [
  "1.1.1.1",
  "1.1.1.2",
  "1.1.1.5",
  "1.1.2.1",
  "1.2.1.2",
  "1.2.1.3",
  "5.1.1.1",
  "5.1.1.2",
  "5.1.1.3",
  "5.1.2.1",
  "5.2.1.2",
  "5.2.1.4",
  "5.2.2.1"
]

const map = {}
const addProp = ([k, ...r], map) => {
  if (r.length === 1) return map[k] ? map[k].push(r[0]) : map[k] = r
  if (map[k]) {
    addProp(r, map[k])
  } else {
    map[k] = {}
    addProp(r, map[k])
  }
}

arr.map(e => e.split('.')).forEach(e => addProp(e, map))

console.log(map)
```

Comment: thank for helping, but, your solution not works correctly. your output dictionary not contain some elements from the array.
for example - 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 . the dictionary only contains  only 
"1": {
    "1": {
      "1": [
        "5"
      ], 
instead of:
"1": {
    "1": {
      "1": [
        "1", "2", "5"
      ],

Comment: @YossiMenasherov Are you sure? It seems to be working fine for me.